# Docker - dotnet build can't find file

Tags: docker

I am trying to make my application work in a Linux container. It will eventually be deployed to Azure Container Instances. I have absolutely no experience with containers what so ever and I am getting lost in the documentation and examples.

I believe the first thing I need to do is create a Docker image for my project. I have installed Docker Desktop.

My project has this structure:

- MyProject

  - MyProject.Core
  - MyProject.Api
  - MyProject.sln
  - Dockerfile

The contents of my Dockerfile is as follows.

```
#Use Ubuntu Linux as base
FROM ubuntu:22.10

#Install dotnet6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dotnet6
#Install LibreOffice
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre-headless libreoffice

#Copy the source code
WORKDIR /MyProject
COPY . ./

#Compile the application
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /compiled

#ENV PORT 80

#Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/compiled/MyProject.Api.dll"]

#ToDo: Split build and deployment
```

Now when I try to build the image using command prompt I am using the following command

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

This all processed okay up until the `dotnet publish` command where it errors saying

> Specify a project or solution file

Now I have verified that this command works fine when run outside of the docker file. I suspect something is wrong with the copy? Again I have tried variations of paths for the WORKDIR, but I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Where is your Dockerfile? You can only copy files from the "Docker Context" which is, essentially, the folder containing the Dockerfile, and anything below it in the tree.

Comment: Also, the usual syntax for building is `docker build .` from the folder containing the Dockerfile

Comment: @SiHa My docker file is at the same level as the solution file, this has sub folders for the 2 individual .csproj files. My folder structure is in the question :)

Comment: @SiHa Using that command with my WORKDIR set to just "app" appears to have worked!! Thank you! :D

Comment: You can run `docker run -it /bin/bash <container>` to go into a container and checkout the folder structure. Where is the file `dotnet` is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SiHa in the comments for providing a solution.

I made the following change to my docker file.

`WORKDIR app`

Then I use the following command to build.

`docker build -t ImageName -f FileName .`

The image now creates successfully. I am able to run this in a container.